# Android, Can I manipulate OS according to my own taste?

Tags: android, operating-system

can I customize my Android OS for myself? for example, Instead of having 6 screen, I change to 10 screen. Or, change the view of default dial tone?

or any changes exactly in OS?

It is just a question, I don't want to do it. But I want to know does OS manipulatable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android OS is open source. This means if you want you can modify the source code and do whatever you want.

A lot of people do similar thing with custom mods. For example the well-known Cyanogen-Mod (http://www.cyanogenmod.com/)